# Linq query dynamic

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

I've this linq query:

```
var query = (from l in _contexto.lineasencargos
                             join a in _contexto.articulos on l.IDARTICULO equals a.IDARTICULO
                             join af in _contexto.articulofamilia on a.IDARTICULO equals af.IDARTICULO
                             join f in _contexto.familias on af.IDFAMILIA equals f.IDFAMILIA
                             join e in _contexto.encargos on l.IDENCARGO equals e.IDENCARGO
                             where e.FECHAHORAENCARGOS >= _finder.FechaDe &&
                                e.FECHAHORAENCARGOS <= _finder.FechaA &&
                                e.FECHAHORARECOGERENCARGOS >= _finder.FechaRecogerDe &&
                                e.FECHAHORARECOGERENCARGOS <= _finder.FechaRecogerA &&
                                e.clientes.RAZONSOCIALCLIENTE.Contains(_finder.Cliente)
                         group l by new  { l.IDARTICULO, l.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO,a.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO,f.DESCRIPCION,f.IDFAMILIA }
                             into g
                                 select new listaEncargosAgrupados
                             {
                                 IdArticulo=(int)g.Key.IDARTICULO,
                                 DescripcionArticulo=g.Key.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO,
                                 IdFamilia=g.Key.IDFAMILIA,
                                 DescripcionFamilia=g.Key.DESCRIPCION,
                                 SumaCantidad = (decimal)g.Sum(x => x.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO),
                                 SumaPrecio = (decimal)g.Sum(x => x.PRECIOLINEAENCARGO),
                                 Total = (decimal)((decimal)g.Sum(x => x.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO) * g.Sum(x => x.PRECIOLINEAENCARGO))
                             });
```

and i need create a condition in **Where**, that filter dynamically:

```
if (_finder.IdTienda > 0)
                {
                    query = query.Where(x=>x.IDTIENDA == _finder.IdTienda); 
                }
```

But this **Where** it is not correct because **IDTIENDA** is contained in **_context.encargos** and not in **listaEncargosAgrupados**

How i can revolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: listaEncargosAgrupados is class and listaEncargosAgrupados  class must contain IDTIENDA  items

Comment: Add IDTIENDA available in _context.encargos in group by clause so that you can project it as public property of listaEncargosAgrupados in the final select projection. Change the group by clause as - `group l by new  { l.IDARTICULO, l.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO,a.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO,f.DESCRIPCION,f.IDFAMILIA , e.IDTIENDA}`

Comment: I don't like IDTIENDA in group by, i need that stay only in the clause where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution to my problem was to employ executestorequery in the context of my EF, and creat a SQL query :

```
List<ListaEncargosAgrupados> lista;
string queryString = @"SELECT l.IDARTICULO,a.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO,f.DESCRIPCION descripcionFamilia,f.IDFAMILIA,sum(l.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO) sumaCantidad,avg(l.PRECIOLINEAENCARGO) 

sumaPrecio,sum(l.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO)*avg(l.PRECIOLINEAENCARGO) Total " +
    "FROM lineasencargos l,articulos a,articulofamilia af,familias f,encargos e " +
    "where a.IDARTICULO=l.IDARTICULO and a.IDARTICULO=af.IDARTICULO " +
    "and af.IDFAMILIA=f.IDFAMILIA and l.IDENCARGO=e.IDENCARGO ";


                if (_finder.IdTienda > 0)
                {
                    queryString = queryString + " and e.idtienda=" + _finder.IdTienda;
                }

                queryString = queryString + " group by l.IDARTICULO,a.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO,f.DESCRIPCION,f.IDFAMILIA order by a.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO ";

                var salidaQuery = _contexto.ExecuteStoreQuery<ListaEncargosAgrupados>(queryString).AsQueryable().ToList();
                lista = salidaQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `e` into grouping statement and `IDTIENDA` list into the result:

```
var query = (from l in _contexto.lineasencargos
                             join a in _contexto.articulos on l.IDARTICULO equals a.IDARTICULO
                             join af in _contexto.articulofamilia on a.IDARTICULO equals af.IDARTICULO
                             join f in _contexto.familias on af.IDFAMILIA equals f.IDFAMILIA
                             join e in _contexto.encargos on l.IDENCARGO equals e.IDENCARGO
                             where e.FECHAHORAENCARGOS >= _finder.FechaDe &&
                                e.FECHAHORAENCARGOS <= _finder.FechaA &&
                                e.FECHAHORARECOGERENCARGOS >= _finder.FechaRecogerDe &&
                                e.FECHAHORARECOGERENCARGOS <= _finder.FechaRecogerA &&
                                e.clientes.RAZONSOCIALCLIENTE.Contains(_finder.Cliente)
                         group new { l, e} by new  { l.IDARTICULO, l.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO,a.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO,f.DESCRIPCION,f.IDFAMILIA }
                             into g
                                 select new { Result = new listaEncargosAgrupados
                             {
                                 IdArticulo=(int)g.Key.IDARTICULO,
                                 DescripcionArticulo=g.Key.DESCRIPCIONARTICULO,
                                 IdFamilia=g.Key.IDFAMILIA,
                                 DescripcionFamilia=g.Key.DESCRIPCION,
                                 SumaCantidad = (decimal)g.Sum(x => x.l.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO),
                                 SumaPrecio = (decimal)g.Sum(x => x.l.PRECIOLINEAENCARGO),
                                 Total = (decimal)((decimal)g.Sum(x => x.l.CANTIDADLINEAENCARGO) * g.Sum(x => x.l.PRECIOLINEAENCARGO))
                             },
                             IDTIENDAs = new HashSet<int>(from x in g
                                                          let id = x.e.IDTIENDA
                                                          where id.HasValue
                                                          select  (int)id.Value)
});
...
if (_finder.IdTienda > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.IDTIENDAs.Contains (_finder.IdTienda));
}
var query1 = query.Select(x => x.Result);
```

Comment: i've compiler error in:  IDTIENDAs = new HashSet<int>(g.Select(x => x.e.IDTIENDA)), Error 4 Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<short?>' a 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<int>', and int     query = query.Where(x => x.IDTIENDAs.Contains(_finder.IdTienda)); Error 5 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' en 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'

Comment: @asirvent what are the types of `e.IDTIENDA` and `_finder.IdTienda`?

Comment: @asirvent `short?`, I suppose. See my fix.

Comment: now i've a compiler error in: query = query.Where(x => x.IDTIENDAs.Contains(_finder.IdTienda)); , Error 3 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' en 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'

Comment: @asirvent please provide a full text program, e.g. via pastebin.com, since I haven't any errors here.

Comment: @asirvent it's because `.ToList()` call at the end of `query` variable definition. Although the variable is implicitly typed, it's still strongly typed - List<AnonymousType> and cannot be set to IEnumerable<AnonymousType>. Just remove `.ToList()` from this statement (line 29) and it should work.

Comment: now, i haven't any compiler errors, but don't work,in var query , i've a null value.